# Zoom to one selection of many

Tags: modeling

I'm cleaning up meshes after boolean operations. There are lots of self-intersecting geometry and I need them all gone.

[image]

Some of the intersections are really tiny and hard to see. When I have all of them selected I want to deselect every "island" of selection but one. Zoom the view to that selection.

I can do it manually by hiding everything else. Select any edge and press L. Zoom extents.

But when I have 400 intersections I wish there was a more automated way of doing it. I can probably code it in python but if someone else already did it.